# How to allow a blank search to be submitted in the standard Search Dialog

Tags: android, search

I'm using the standard Search Dialog (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)) and everything is up and working fine but I now realise I can't search on a blank string.

I'm assuming there must be a flag somewhere which will allow this but can't seem to find **where** this flag is. Could someone please point me to it?

Comment: why on earth would you want to search for a blank string???

Comment: Unfortunately one of those "because it's mandatory in the spec" pieces of functionality. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SearchDialog.java in android source code:

```
// If there is text in the query box, handle enter, and action keys
// The search key is handled by the dialog's onKeyDown().
if (!mSearchAutoComplete.isEmpty()) {
    ...
```

So, looks like it isn't possible to set a flag to make blank searches possible.

Comment: Had to create an entire bespoke search with suggestion drop down because it turned out to be easier than overriding.